# jQuery Select2 clears the input value on clicking anywhere?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am working on a project where I am using jquery select2 for making tags. Everything is working perfectly fine except one thing. 
Select2 forcefully clear the input value ( which is not created as a tag ) on clicking outside.

for example.
in the below screenshot when i enter xyz and click outside the tag selector it clear the xyz.
 [image]

I don't want to clear the value.

How to force Select2 for not clearing the value?

I google it but did't got lucky and also there is no option in select2 docs

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

this is how am using

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="tagSelect" value="brown,red,green" style="width:300px;" />
```

JS

```
$('#tagSelect').select2({
 tags: ["red", "green", "blue"],
 minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
 dropdownCss:{"display": "none"},
 tokenSeparators: [",",13," "]
});
```

Comment: thats the default behavior of select2.

Comment: I think you need `createSearchChoice` option.
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: @RohitBatra yes you are right this is the default behaviour. am surprised to know that there is no option to stop it or i didn't find any?

Comment: @mishik How this createSearchChoice help me from not clearing the input data? in my knowledge `createSearchChoice` is used to `Creates a new selectable choice from user's search term.`

Comment: @user1430001 I was just looking into their code. If you want you can try to edit it Check this https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js Line::1464 what you need to try will be comment out this line this.clearSearch(); and maybe it would not do then. Try making a jsfiddle of your problem so I can also test it out for you.

Comment: @RohitBatra using your idea yeah i found out that the `clearSearch` is the function which remove the input value.

https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js#L2915.
is there any way to overwrite this function without editing plugin?

Comment: @user1430001 I don't know any such way we can do this without editing the code/plugin. Why don't you open up a thread in github with the creator asking a round-about your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending time in Select2 code i finally found a solution to overwrite the `clearSearch` function so it will not clear the value until user make it a tag.

Select2 give us option to overwrite any function.

`window.Select2` they insert the select2 object into windows object so if we need any customisation

CODE:

```
        window.Select2.class.multi.prototype.clearSearch=function(){
            var placeholder = this.getPlaceholder(),
                maxWidth = this.getMaxSearchWidth();
           // CurrentThisInput=(this.search); i used this to get the current select2 element and make further action if required.
            if(this.search.val()!=""){}else
            if (placeholder !== undefined  && this.getVal().length === 0 &&  this.search.val()=="") {
                this.search.val(placeholder).addClass("select2-default");
                this.search.width(maxWidth > 0 ? maxWidth : this.container.css("width"));
            }
        }
```

Thank you all for support